# Como adicionar valor limite junto com jquery mask?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input, mask

Galera estou usando o plugin da máscara deste link: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Eu uso o seguinte jquery pra fazer a máscara:

```
$('.decimal').mask('000,0', {reverse: true});
```

No entanto eu preciso que o valor máximo seja 100,0.
Já tentei colocar

```
$('.decimal').mask('100,0', {reverse: true});
```

Mas não funciona pois o **0** significa qualquer número então a pessoa pode colocar até 199,9.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode o evento [`onKeyPress`](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#mask-as-a-function), substituir a virgula pelo ponto e verificar se é maior que 100.0:

```
$('.decimal').mask('000,0', {
  reverse: true,
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
    if (val.replace(',', '.') > 100.0) {
      $('.decimal').val('')
    }
  }
});
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
$('.decimal').mask('000,0', {
  reverse: true,
  onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
    if (val.replace(',', '.') > 100.0) {
      console.clear();
      console.log('Valor maximo 100,0 !');
      $('.decimal').val('');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="decimal">
```

#### Referência:

- [jQuery Mask Plugin - Mask as a function](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#mask-as-a-function)